# Plotly express: Grouped and stacked of specific data colomns

Tags: python, plotly

I have a table of 6 columns, as follows:

[image]

I need to prepare a graph of stacked and grouped like the following (I didn't show here the E, but it is in the column of C & D):

[image]

I've tried using this line:

```
px.bar(df2, x="Year", y=["Year", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], barmode="group").show()
```

But obviously it does not work as expected (since I don't know how to 'tell' which columns I want to stack together).

I get this graph:

[image]

Can anyone help me define the columns I want to stack? (i.e., A & B, C & D & E).

I want to do it in plotly.express.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is a grouping of stacked graphs, but as far as I know, there is no easy way to achieve this. So I created the data structure based on an example of creating a graph from multiple indices. The reference's can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#multicategorical-axes). I manually created multiple indexes for the x-axis and specified the columns for each. The limitation with this graph is that the column names are required. The spacing of bars per group cannot be adjusted as in the expected output graph.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[[2019,2020,2021],['AB','AB','AB']], y=df['A'], name='A'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[[2019,2020,2021],['AB','AB','AB']], y=df['B'], name='B'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[[2019,2020,2021],['CD','CD','CD']], y=df['C'], name='C'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[[2019,2020,2021],['CD','CD','CD']], y=df['D'], name='D'))

fig.update_traces(selector=dict(type='bar'), width=[0.85,0.85,0.85,0.85,0.85,0.85]) 
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, barmode='stack', bargap=0.0, bargroupgap=0.0, legend=dict(traceorder='normal'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it is not grouped of stacked elements. In Google there are many examples, just could not find something I can work with.

Comment: You need to clearly point out what exactly is different. Both your response and the images in your question are groupings of stacked graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found these 2 links which do exactly what I need:
https://dev.to/fronkan/stacked-and-grouped-bar-charts-using-plotly-python-a4p
[stacked barplot in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563166/stacked-barplot-in-plotly)